# wrapping vector image onto bitmap

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How were these images composited, given the design elements are made in [image]vector format.  Which tool was used to composite this image?

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those decorative drawings on the vehicles can be created as vector graphics. But thats not at all essential question when one wants to put them on the photos of the vehicles.

Placing drawings onto photos which are taken of vehicles or miniature models is possible. Drawings must be clipped, warped and shaded to make them fit. Unfortunately the amount of needed work and skill is enormous - it simply is beyond the possiblities of most of us, if the result must be photorealistic like your examples and there's no time to work using the trial and error -method.

Today the job is done otherwise. There's a 3D model of the vehicle. Pro level 3D software allows laying images onto surfaces. They call it UV-mapping. U and V refer to the usual names of the surface coordinates of 3D models. Using 3D also needs skill and talent, but the process is much more easily manageable after one has fought himself over the learning phase. The details are beyond the scope of this answer.

Commercial software that can handle this job have premium price. An example of free pro quality 3D software for this job is Blender. Also some top notch CAD software is possible, because they are designed for exact mechanical constructions. But the cost is thousands of US dollars.

All software that can handle this is complex. The learning of the basics takes weeks and there's no hope to be productive until after months and that's with having proper training. Starting Blender or other up-to-the task software and trying to find the way by trial and error leads to nothing.